# reading a C++ ifstream twice?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

How to read a file twice (e.g. like an old two-pass assembler do) using `std::ifstream`?

I tried the obvious

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  std::string path = argc>1?std::string{argv[1]}:std::string(__FILE__);
  std::ifstream inp{path};
  int num=0;
  std::cout << "first pass" << std::endl;
  do {
    std::string lin;
    std::getline(inp,lin);
    if (inp.eof())
      break;
    num++;
    std::cout << "#" << num << ":" << lin << std::endl;
  } while (!inp.eof());
  inp.seekg(0, inp.beg);
  inp.sync();
  std::cout << "second pass" << std::endl;
  num=0;
  do {
    std::string lin;
    std::getline(inp,lin);
    if (inp.eof())
      break;
    num++;
    std::cout << "##" << num << ":" << lin << std::endl;
  } while (!inp.eof());
  inp.close();
  return 0;
}
```

and it does not work (the second loop is looping indefinitely).

FWIW, compiling with GCC 4.9.2 on Linux/x86-64/Debian

#### precisions

Actually I am trying to parse a file made of lines like `** somename` followed (in the next lines) by a JSON object, followed by some empty newlines (and repeatedly again perhaps a `** someothername` followed by another JSON object etc...). I need a two-pass algorithm. The first pass is extracting all the names (like `somename`) and building some "empty" named things. The second pass is filling the named things from the JSON object following them. JSON parsing is done using a recent 1.5 `jsoncpp` library.

Comment: clear bad flags may be ? `inp.clear();`

Comment: "second loop is looping indefinitely" and printing what?..

Comment: I have this problem months ago, see my question-answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331017/rewind-an-ifstream-object-after-hitting-the-end-of-file

Comment: You should not use `ifstream::eof()` to control the reading loop.  You should be using your file read operation to control the loop.  that way once the read fails the loop stops.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: What is the point of `while (!inp.eof());`? When will it ever hit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewind an ifstream object after hitting the end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331017/rewind-an-ifstream-object-after-hitting-the-end-of-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last call to [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) upon reaching end-of-stream fails, setting [`failbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). Since `failbit` is set, the call to [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) has no effect. You need to [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the stream's status flags before calling `seekg` ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d90b11b43f0459f3)):

```
namespace {
void one_pass(std::istream& is) {
  std::string lin;
  for (int num = 0; std::getline(is, lin); ++num) {
    std::cout << '#' << num << ':' << lin << '\n';
  }
}
} // unnamed namespace

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  std::ifstream inp{argc > 1 ? argv[1] : __FILE__};

  std::cout << "first pass\n";
  one_pass(inp);

  inp.clear();
  inp.seekg(0);

  std::cout << "\nsecond pass\n";
  one_pass(inp);
}
```